# Which service does Amazon use for EC2 activation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phone-call, activation

When signing up for Amazon EC2 I had to activate the service using my phone. I clicked a button that said "Call me now", then amazon displayed a PIN on my screen which I then had to key in my phone once I received a phone call from them. Once the call was completed my screen automatically updated and said I was approved.

Which service allows Amazon to do this? I know they're Twilio and other services but I'm wondering if anyone knows which service/API they use.

Comment: Do you need to specifically know what Amazon is using, or is your question more about what a good API for accomplishing this sort of task is, regardless of what Amazon happens to have chosen?

Comment: I use simply curious if anyone knew. I've heard and been using Twilio. I was wondering if there was any other service available.

Comment: I am fairly confident they use something internal that wouldn't be available to us on the outside. Probably the same thing that powers SNS, which can also send texts.

Comment: Unlikely that they use Twilio as Twilio doesn't offer many international locations. I can't get Twilio to send text messages to Costa Rica and Amazon sent me a text. Maybe they use Clickatell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that with Twillio. I just recently played with their API ([through the PHP library they provide](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries)) and they make these kinds of things trivial.

So in this case, it sounds like you want Gather:
http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather

On top of the their markup, you can constantly poll for the status of a call, etc. so you can update your own application in real time, e.g. to reflect that the call finished or if the input was correct or incorrect.